# Create a label with close button

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am looking for the best way to create a label with the close button in it. Do I need to place a button in the label or can i use the label as a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom UIView and use touch at specific location to dismiss that uiview which i think acts similar to close button in functionality.

and to remove that view use the following code to recognize the touch on the custom view in touches began method:

```
CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:buttonlabel];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(buttonlabel.bounds, [touches.anyObject  locationInView:buttonlabel])==YES){
        if ( (your desired location) ) {

            NSLog(@"pressed close button");
            [buttonlabel removeFromSuperview]; //here when i clicked on top right,only the last view that is added is getting removed

      }
```